# Can I use CouchDB's new partitioned databases to only replicate a specific partition?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, offline-caching, couchdb-3.x

I'm super excited about CouchDB 3, especially the Partitioned Database feature. I would like to set up something similar to envoy, where you have one database that syncs to many smaller databases.

I was wondering, what's the best way to implement one partition for one user, and only enable users to sync their own partitions. Is it possible to have global changes split into partition changes, using that log for syncing, or is that overthinking on my part?

Comment: I see [no evidence](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation) that this is directly supported. But you can, of course, do filtered replication along the same dimensions as your partitioning.

Comment: Filter replication would be a good start, but if you have many users on one db, then using filter would still need to scan through all users sync log and pickout current user changes.  So far the only idea that im having is making my own custom chages log for each user, this is going away from couch db replication and towards a custom one

Answer (score 1):

You can add a selector to the replication document.

```
"selector": { "_id": { "$regex": "^[PartitionName]:" } }
```

Comment: Was the use of square brackets (i.e. a character class) in the regex deliberate? Should it read `"^PartitionName:" or does it need to match literal brackets, e.g. `"^\[PartitionName\]:"` ?  (possibly double backslashes are needed)

Answer (score -1):

You are right , the brackets expression should be replace by the actual partition name - final expression should be without brackets..

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a selector to the replication document.

e.g.

```
"selector": { "_id": { "$regex": "^CANADA:" } }
```

or

```
"selector": { "_id": { "$regex": "^USA:" } }
```